# How loop through two pandas df columns at the same time and the result is a boolean from 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas

How loop through two pandas df columns at the same time and the result is a boolean from 2 if/else conditions.  I tried using zip. For example:

```
terms = []
end_date = df201911_final_copy['YMDEND']
future_planID = df201911_final_copy['FUTURE_PLAN_ID']
rows = zip(end_date, future_planID)
for row in rows:
    if end_date is not None and future_planID is None:
        terms.append(1)
    else:
        terms.append(0)
```

But this gives me a list of the expected length but only 0s but I know that there ARE records where these two conditions are met.  I guessing zip isnt the correct method but I'm not sure what method to use.

Comment: `terms = df201911_final_copy[['YMEND', 'FUTURE_PLAN_ID']].notnull().all(1)`.

Comment: Beautiful @QuangHoang

Comment: add `.astype(int)` if you want 1 or 0 instead True or False

Comment: @QuangHoang Im not sure if this is the results Im looking for though.  Can you explain how this works?  Its filling all records that are not null with a 1 (True).  But I only want True when YMDEND is not null but FUTURE_PLAN_ID is null.  I think this is just filling all records where both are null with True.  I cant tell

Comment: @BenSmith Sorry, I didn't get the `not` part. you can do: `df201911_final_copy['YMEND'].notnull() & df201911_final_copy['FUTURE_PLAN_ID'].isna()`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you!